# Dijkstra's Algorithm c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I am supposed to implement a Dijkstra's algorithm with an adjacency matrix and a distance array. These are implemented through the class `Graph300`. The program inputs a file with a weighted matrix and it is getting into the matrix fine.

The distance array is outputted for the user. But my Dijkstras is not working correctly. I keep getting `UINT_MAX` for every vertex except the starting vertex (user specified) :

```
Input matrix (4x4):
0           5           10           4294967295
4294967295  0           4294967295   3
4294967295  7           0            4294967295
4294967295  4294967295  4            0

My distance array should output:
distance[0]=4294967295 -nopath
distance[1]=0  -startnode
distance[2]=7
distance[3]=3

My output now (that is wrong):
distance[0]=4294967295 -nopath
distance[1]=0  -startnode
distance[2]=4294967295
distance[3]=4294967295
```

Here is my algorithm; `numberNodes` is the the dimension of the vertex. `startNode` is user specified. The matrix array and distance array are of type `unsigned int`:

```
void Graph300::dijkstra300()
{
    int startNode=getStartNode300();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberNodes; i++)
        distanceArray[i] = UINT_MAX;

    distanceArray[startNode] = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < numberNodes-1; count++)
    {
         unsigned int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

         for (int v = 0; v < numberNodes; v++)
             if (visitedSet[v] == false && distanceArray[v] <= min)
                 min = distanceArray[v], min_index = v;

         int u = min_index;
         visitedSet[u] = true;

         for (int v = 0; v < numberNodes; v++)
             if (!visitedSet[v] && adjacencyMatrix[u][v] && distanceArray[u] != UINT_MAX
                && distanceArray[u]+adjacencyMatrix[u][v] < distanceArray[v])
                  distanceArray[v] = distanceArray[u] + adjacencyMatrix[u][v];
    }
    view300();  // display result
}
```

Comment: "*is not working correctly*" is not specific enough for us to help.  Please provide the information to be reproductible:  what input do you have, what output do you get, and what outpout do you expect ?

Comment: 'Sorry if my code spacing is weird. I always have it copy over weird' There are a lot of editor out there that can format your code accordingly. As a sugestion, use it, it will be a lot easy to read.

Comment: could you tell the type of distanceArray[] and of adjacencyMatrix[][] ?

Comment: Ok !  Now with your test data and usage of unsigned int, I could find the problem (see updated solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First look:

It's difficult to be 100% sure to solve the issue, because you didn't show us the class member types nor a typical example of failure.  Nevertheless a confustion pops to the eye:  is the type of distanceArray[] `unsigned int` or `int` ?

Here you assume it's unsigned:

```
distanceArray[i] = UINT_MAX;
```

But later you compare this unsigned with a signed integer:

```
int min = INT_MAX, min_index;   // min is signed integer !

for (int v = 0; v < numberNodes; v++)
   if (... && distanceArray[v] <= min)  // when comparing signed and unsigned you might not get the expected result !!
```

Mismatches between signed and unsigned might lead to unexpected results in your comparison (see [online demo](http://ideone.com/6gZarm)).  To avoid this kind of issues, either you work only with unsigned values, or, change all your `UINT_MAX` to `INT_MAX`.

### Solution

I could find out the problem with the additional data you provided, and switching all distances to unsigned int. You have to correct your `if`:

```
        if (!visitedSet[v] && adjacencyMatrix[u][v] && adjacencyMatrix[u][v] != UINT_MAX  
            && distanceArray[u] + adjacencyMatrix[u][v] < distanceArray[v])
```

because you have to consider only existing edges (`adjacencyMatrix[u][v]!= UINT_MAX`).  In your code you made the comparison with `distanceArray`.

I could run your code (outside of a class) and with your input obtain the expected output.  Here the [online demo](http://ideone.com/sZJuYU).

Comment: I updated it to unsigned int. The arrays are unsigned. However, it did not change my output.